# Apply 2 different CSS pseudo-elements to the same class on the same time

Tags: css

It is correct to apply 2 different CSS pseudo-elements to the same class `on the same time`?

Browser interpret my desired result, at least on Firefox everything works fine, but for me is important if this is a correct approach.

Do you have a correct CSS approach of this scenario?

```css
.critselect {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.critselect p:nth-child(2) {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
.critselect p:nth-child(2):first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="critselect">
<p class="randvis">This is first paragraph and have <strong>CRM / Marketing</strong> or others extrnaly inserted values that must remain Uppercase.</p>
<p class="randvis">This is second paragraph and have <strong>French, English, German</strong> or others eternaly inserted values that must to be converted via CSS to lowercase.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What you are using here a pseudo-classes, not pseudo-elements.... And yes, you can do that without problem.

Comment: Thank you for information. What is strange on this scenario is that tags like H1, H2 etc are treated as paragraphs and the pseudo-classes affect them too.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's correct to apply two different CSS pseudo-class to the same class, 
but in your scenario..., I do not see it very feasible, it is better to use

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

it is also not necessary to use the

```
important!
```

is bad practice

Comment: My friend capitalize affect all the row, each word from paragraph will become uppercase, that is not what I looking for.

Comment: My friend, when you use the pseudo-elements `p:nth-child(2):first-letter` , only you make reference to first character of the paragraph, but with `text-transform: capitalize;`, you understand that the first letter is capitalized and not all the text.